# linux gfortran gdb error During startup program exited with code 126

Tags: linux, fortran, gdb, gfortran

I have a Fortran program that I wrote, and ran, in 1996 that I am trying to import to gfortran 95.

After editing I compiled the source code:

```
gfortran -c -g -fno-align-commons MT3Dm2.f95 -o MT3Dm2
```

which generated no error messages.

I then ran gdb and got:

```
Success
During startup program exited with code 126.
```

Googling the error message resulted in nothing that I could understand.

Pointers on how to proceed will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you happen to come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476243/gdb-is-showing-program-exited-during-startup)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

```
gfortran -c -g -fno-align-commons MT3Dm2.f95 -o MT3Dm2
```

produces a relocatable object file (because you told the compiler to only *compile*, but not link with the `-c` flag).

I suspect that you are trying to run the resulting `MT3Dm2` as if it were an executable (which it is *not*). You must actually link the executable:

```
gfortran -g -fno-align-commons MT3Dm2.f95 -o MT3Dm2
```

or, if you prefer to keep compile and link steps separate:

```
gfortran -c -g -fno-align-commons MT3Dm2.f95
gfortran -g MT3Dm2.o -o MT3Dm2
```

Comment: Thanks your response, it solved the immediate problem.  I still have some editing to do.